# Congruent Triangles and Right Angles

Tags: geometry

The sides $AB$ and $AC$ of $\triangle ABC$ are constructed towards the exterior of the squares $ABDE$ and $ACFG$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and let $N$ be the point of intersection of $AM$ and $EG$. Prove that $EG = 2AM$ and $\angle ANE = 90^\circ$.

I extended $AM$ to a point $P$ such that $AM = MP$. I am trying to show that $AP = EG$ by congruent triangles to prove $EG = 2AM$ but I am having trouble proving $\triangle ACP$ and $\triangle GAE$ congruent. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of square $ACFG$. Perform clockwise $90^{\circ}-$rotation around point $O$. Then point $A$ is mapped to $G$, point $C$ is mapped to $A$ and $P$ is mapped to $E$. Triangles $ACP$ and $GAE$ are images of each other under this rotation, so they are congruent. You can prove their congruence directly too. But the rotation immediately gives you that $EG = PA = 2AM$ (image under rotation) and $AM$ is orthogonal to $EG$ because the line $EG$ is the $90^{\circ}-$rotation image of $AM$.

$ABPC$ is a parallelogram because its diagonals $AP$ and $BC$ split each other in half. Then $CP = AB = AE$. Also $CA = AG$ and $\angle \, PCA = 180^{\circ} - \angle \, BAC = \angle \, EAG$. Therefore $CPA$ is congruent to $EAG$.

Comment: i am stuck on how to prove their congruence directly...without rotations @Futurologist

Comment: @danish see edit

Comment: why does $\angle PCA$ = $180^\circ - \angle BAC$?

Comment: @danish $ABPC$ is a parallelogram. Then $\angle \, BAC+ \angle \, PCA = 180^{\circ}$.

Comment: is there a way to derive from this way that $\angle ANE = 90^\circ$?

Comment: @danish yes. $\angle \, AEN = \angle \, AEG = \angle \, CPA = \angle \, BAP$ because $AB || CP$. But $A \in NP$ so $$180^{\circ} = \angle \, NAE + \angle \, EAB + \angle \, BAP = \angle \, NAE + 90^{\circ} + \angle \, BAP$$ so $ \angle \, NAE + \angle \, BAP =90^{\circ}$. However, $\angle \, AEN = \angle \, BAP$ so $ \angle \, NAE + \angle \, AEN =90^{\circ}$.

Comment: i can see that since $AB||CP$ that $\angle CPA = \angle BAP$ what i am not seeing is how that implies that $\angle BAP = \angle AEG$ @Futurologist

Comment: wait...since $\triangle ACP \equiv \triangle EAG$ their angles are congruent...and with the alternate interior angles we already know it is implied. got it